# Find specific Value in json api call

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api

Can I find the `close` price of this stock even though the date on the API is constantly changing?

API:

```
'Time Series (1min)': {  
     '2017-12-19 13:01:00':{  
           '1. open':'196.4100',
           '2. high':'196.5075',
           '3. low':'196.3800',
           '4. close':'196.3800',
           '5. volume':'4961'
            }
}
```

Python Code:

```
print('Grabbing stock price...')
ourl = req.get(url)
im = ourl.json()
return im #return closing price
```

Comment: I just need to know how to organize the string to get the closing price, example: im['Time Series (1min)'][0]['4. close']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you almost had it in your own example, just replace `0` with the actual date.

```
im['Time Series (1min)']['2017-12-19 13:01:00']['4. close']
# output '196.3800'
```

Edited for looping:

the thing for `dict` is, you are not indexing a `dict`, you access the items using keys. that's the very main purpose of having a key value pair. 
or probably more correctly, don't use `dict` when you need to index something.

I would suggest you use something like `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd

# option 1
df = pd.DataFrame(ourl.json())
df.columns = ['Meta', 'TS']  # save time typing spaces
return df.TS[2]['4. close']

# option 2
df = pd.DataFrame(ourl.json())
return df.iloc[:, 1][2]['4. close']

# output 
  '196.3800'
```

this way you can return a single value every time you fetch an item and return just the value, by indexing.(partially)

P.S. you didn't tell us what `ourl.json()` returns, i am assuming it is returning a dictionary here. in particular, what you wanted to do is indexing correctly, organising string sounds a bit confusing to me.. as we are not actually organising a string :)

Comment: This would work but `['2017-12-19 13:01:00']` is constantly changing, so I would have to use an index as this API returns multiple dates and I want the most recent one

Comment: This still does not work, giving me and error of: `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 1 elements`

Comment: that means your json is return something different this time, can you check? for what you posted above as the result return, it's definitely working provided the structure is constant

Comment: My api call is returning exactly this (Remember I want to get the closing price of the most recent time): https://pastebin.com/7c3LX37Z

Comment: I am behind proxy, can't see file sharing sorry... if you don't mind could you add it to your question, so I can take a look now, otherwise let me go home first :)

Comment: It is not a file, it is a website

Comment: `{  
   'Meta Data':{  
      '1. Information':'Intraday (1min) prices and volumes',
      '2. Symbol':'NVDA',
      '3. Last Refreshed':'2017-12-19 13:53:00',
      '4. Interval':'1min',
      '5. Output Size':'Compact',
      '6. Time Zone':'US/Eastern'
   },
   'Time Series (1min)':{  
      '2017-12-19 13:53:00':{  
         '1. open':'196.8600',
         '2. high':'196.8945',
         '3. low':'196.8000',
         '4. close':'196.8198',
         '5. volume':'1630'
      }`
Thats the first part, as it doesnt let me show you all of it

Comment: @Shtabbbe updated according to your json object shared.

Answer (score 0):

Use `im.items()` to convert your dict to a tupples. Then use indexes to access the elements.

```
im = {
    'Time Series (1min)': {
        '2017-12-19 13:01:00': {
            '1. open': '196.4100',
            '2. high': '196.5075',
            '3. low': '196.3800',
            '4. close': '196.3800',
            '5. volume': '4961'
        }
    }
}
```

For **Python 2**

```
print im['Time Series (1min)'].items()[0][1]['4. close'] # prints 196.3800
```

for **Python 3**, this should change as follows

```
print(list(a['Time Series (1min)'].items())[0][1]['4. close']) # prints 196.3800
```

or you can loop through `a['Time Series (1min)'].items()` iterable

Comment: Whenever I try to do index it at [0] I get this error:

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    grabstock('NVDA')
  File "C:\Users\bobby\Desktop\Code\Python\bitcoin bot.py", line 24, in grabstock
    return tuple1[0]
TypeError: 'dict_items' object does not support indexing`

Comment: `def grabstock(symbol):
    print('Grabbing stock price...')
    url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol='+str(symbol)+'&interval=1min&apikey=HMAI6PZDJ8JYLF5W'
    ourl = req.get(url)
    im = ourl.json()
    return im['Time Series (1min)'].items()[0][1]['4. close']`

Comment: sorry for the bad formatting, Stack overflow doesn't like spaces or tabs

Comment: it's wrong; `dict.items()` gives you a `dict_items` object, it doesn't give you `tuple`.

Comment: @stucash That's a problem with the python version. My bad for not mentioning the python version. It seems that the behavior of dict.items() has been changed in python 3. The above code works fine in python 2.7

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda thanks for updating it. likewise, I should mentioned it was only wrong for python3!

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative for extracting the prices without knowledge of the time would be to use the `urllib.request` package with the `json` package and a bit of looping:

```
import json
import urllib.request

def extract_json(f):
    json_decode = json.load(f)
    time_series = json_decode['Time Series (1min)']
    for data in time_series:
        print(time_series[data]['3. low'])

opener = urllib.request.FancyURLopener({})
url = "http://localhost:8092/sample_json.json"
f = opener.open(url)
extract_json(f)
```

If the input on the server is:

```
{
  "Time Series (1min)": {
    "2017-12-19 13:01:00": {
      "1. open": "196.4100",
      "2. high": "196.5075",
      "3. low": "196.3800",
      "4. close": "196.3800",
      "5. volume": "4961"
    }
  }
}
```

The result of running the script is:

```
196.3800
```

Tried on this version:

```
3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 17:54:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
```